# Моделирование процесса нагрева металла в 3D

Tags: анимация, моделирование, физика, движок, 3d

Мне поставили задачу, где я должен написать программу моделирования процесса нагрева металла под воздействием точечного источника, в виде градиента температуры. 
С матчастью проблемы нет, физический процесс программным путем описать в состоянии, но как визуализировать весь этот процесс? Мог бы составить 2D модель из под Canvas в Delphi, но это будет смотреться по детски.
 Есть навыки 3Д моделирования 3DSM, AutoCAD, и т.д.
Есть навыки программирования C++, Delphi, Assembler, Python.
Но с генерацией 3D модели путем написания кода ни разу не сталкивался, так же, как и с программной анимацией. Может кто подскажет, в какую сторону копать нужно? Потому, что столько разновидностей 3D движков, что я просто потеряю все сроки, пока буду знакомиться с ними, какой более удобен и прост для моей задачи?

Comment: Думаю, самое простое - это OpenGL. Вам же только нарисовать один объект и разлить по нему радиальный градиент...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону [Qt + Quick 3D](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133126/) ну или напрямую с библиотекой [QtOpenGL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132674/) поработайте.